# Emacs macro to generate a sequence?

Tags: emacs

I was reading this article on how to create vi macros:
[vi sequence macro](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/) and I saw one useful macro to create a sequence in the buffer.

1.
2.
...
100.

In vi, the trick is that one can hit ctrl-a over a number and it will add one to it, so this made the macro easy.  I want to be able to do the same thing in emacs.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you are using Emacs 23 (and maybe 22?), use `kmacro-insert-counter` which is bound to `C-x C-k TAB` by default.  So for your example, you'd do:

`C-x ( C-x C-k TAB . RET C-x )`

So start macro, insert counter followed by '.', newline, end macro.  Then `C-x e e e e e e e` etc.  Or `M-1 0 0 C-x e` to get 100 of them.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention you can set the counter to an initial value also.  For example to start at 1 instead of 0 do `M-1 C-x C-k C-c`.

And if you don't want the counter to increment at a particular point, prefix it with `C-u`.  Of course the keystrokes are getting a bit ridiculous at this point, so I usually bind a key to insert-but-don't-increment.

Comment: Still relevant:

    `kmacro-set-counter            C-x C-k C-c`
    `kmacro-add-counter            C-x C-k C-a`
    `kmacro-insert-counter         C-x C-k TAB`

So the idea is, set the counter.  Then define the macro and within the macro insert-and-increment the counter.  Then repeatedly run the macro. 

This may have been obvious to other readers but I didn't initially get it.

Comment: Forgot that you can just hit `e` to repeat the macro after the initial `C-x e`.

Answer (score 62):

Those who feel there are too many tricks to memorize might find acquiring some elisp more profitable:

```
M-: (dotimes (i 20) (insert (format "%2d.\n" (1+ i))))
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `M-:` (`eval-expression`), I never heard about it.

Comment: @TörökGábor `\,(eval-expression)` is neat in query replace regexps, too.

Answer (score 18):

Emacs 23 supports elisp snippets in the replacement text of replace-regexp.

I frequently define keyboard macros that follow this pattern:

- Copy a block of text
- Navigate to a number that I want to increment in the copied block of text with isearch
- Activate the mark and move the point to define a region encompassing the number
- M-x replace-regexp
- At the "Replace regexp" prompt, enter `\([0-9]+\)` to capture a group of one or more digits
- At the "Replace regexp ([0-9]+) with:" prompt, enter `\,(1+ \#1)`, where `,` indicates that an elisp form to substitute follows, `1+` is an increment function, and `\#1` is the first captured match text, interpreted as a number.

After taking a minute to define the keyboard macro, this allows me to have almost the convenience of cutting and pasting to generate lots of blocks of almost-identical code, such as for `case` statements.

Note that this technique can be easily adapted to e.g. double numbers (`\,(* 2 \#1)`) or whatever.  You can even use it to substitute the next element in an arbitrary sequence by using a combination of `'position` and `'nth`, but I won't go into that now :).

Comment: thanks for demonstrating how to use replace-regexp to substitute a counter for text

Comment: `\,(eval-expression)` is very neat in query replace regexps! I had to renumber a sequence of superscript numbers starting from 1. They were all in SMF `[sup]` tags, starting with 63. So I did this query replace regexp to start them from 1: `(default \[sup\][0-9]+\[\/sup\]`→ `[sup]\,(kmacro-insert-counter 1)[/sup]`. However, it replaced them with with something like  [sup]New macro counter value: 1 (1)[/sup]00". How could I fix this (besides regexping that extra text out)?

Comment: @Geremia: Here's what I had to do: `C`-`:` `(setq kmacro-counter 0)` and then: `\[sup\][0-9]+\[\/sup\]`→`[sup]\,(print (setq kmacro-counter (1+ kmacro-counter)))`.

Answer (score 15):

Since release 24.3 of Emacs (I believe actually since release 24.0), the keystroke sequence has been simplified:

`<F3> <F3> . <ENTER> <F4>`

Then repeating `<F4>` key will repeat the macro.

The trick is that, after having started a macro with `<F3>`, a second `<F3>` key press will insert the current value of the keyboard macro's counter into the buffer, and increments the counter by 1.

Other tricks:

- `<F3> C-u 2 <F3> . <ENTER> <F4>` will increment with +2 (instead of +1)
- `C-u 100 <F3> <F3> . <ENTER> C-u 50 <F4>` will start at 100 and finish at 149
- `C-x C-k C-f %03d <ENTER> <F3> <F3> . <ENTER> <F4>` will pad with zero like "000"

Source: [Keyboard Macro Counter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html) section in Emacs manual.

Comment: To preset the counter, you just need a numeric prefix arg. e.g.: `C-u 100 <f3> <f3> . RET <f4>`. A prefix argument to `<f4>` says how many times to repeat the macro (inclusive of recording), so to count from 100 to 149 immediately you could finish that with `C-u 50 <f4>` instead of just `<f4>`.

Comment: Thanks phils. I improved my answer (and knowledge) with your comments.

Comment: `F3 F3 X F4` is a **huge** improvement over `C-x ( C-x C-k TAB X C-x )` in terms of ease of use for a throwaway-macro - and now I don't have to come here because I forgot the key acrobatics combo. I hope this answer will bubble up to the top, where it belongs.

Comment: Hasn't this been in Emacs since at least Emacs 23? Because I distinctly remember this being a thing in Emacs 23. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Beside [scottfrazer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509688/emacs-macro-to-generate-a-sequence/1510038#1510038), there is another way to create a sequence of numbers with [CUA mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) which may help you a lot when editing existing content. See [Mark Mansour's screencast on Emacs Column Editing](http://vimeo.com/1168225?pg=embed&sec=1168225) from position 2:30.

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on the CUA minor mode (`cua-mode`), you can select a column of text and then fill it with a sequence of numbers using `cua-sequence-rectangle` (bound to `M-n` by default).

This is the same thing mentioned in the video Török Gábor linked to, but now it's written down here so you don't have to watch the whole video unless you want to.  It is a good video.

Comment: It's also worth noting that these days you don't need `cua-mode`* to number a rectangle -- since 24.1 there's a regular rectangle operation `rectangle-number-lines` bound to `C-x r N`. (* or `cua-selection-mode`, which is definitely the preferable option for those who don't use `cua-mode` as standard.)

Comment: I may as well link to [emacs string-insert-rectangle vector of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9932745/324105) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [extension](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/macro-math/) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

There's also:

`C-u M-! jot -s '.C-q C-j' 10`

It's not pure elisp, but has the same effect. You could write a named macro to run it for you.

Comment: 'jot' and 'seq' do the same thing for these purposes. If you're on Unix, you almost surely have at least one of them installed.q

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shell-command-on-region` otherwise :

```
C-u M-! seq 1 100|xargs -I{} echo {}"."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple defun for this:

```lisp
(defun insert-range (START END &optional STEP FORMAT)
  "Inserts a range of integers from START to END with STEP (default to 1)
in a given format (default to \"\\n%d\")"
  (interactive
   (list (read-number "Start: " 1)
         (read-number "End: "  10)
         (read-number "Step: "  1)
         (read-string "Format (default to \"\\n%d\"): " nil nil "\n%d") ))
  (dotimes (i (1+ (/ (- END START) STEP)))
    (insert (format FORMAT (+ START (* i STEP))))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a sequence of counters starting from `START` and with step `STEP` using

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> `START` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>C-u</kbd> `STEP` <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>F4</kbd>,

where `…` is anything else you want to include in your macro. This inserts the first counter, with value `START`. Afterwards, <kbd>F4</kbd> will insert the next value in the sequence. If you skip the setting of `START` (i.e. if you do just <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>C-u</kbd> `STEP` <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>F4</kbd>) it'll start from 0. You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> to specify the format of the counter.

You can also insert `N` elements of the sequence starting at `START` and with step `STEP` using [huaiyuan's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1512270/4413019): type <kbd>M-:</kbd> and enter

```lisp
(dotimes (i N) (insert (format "%2d.\n" (+ START (* i STEP)))))
```