# How to increment a serie of number on the same row in a configuration file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Let say I have a configuration file, and each lines contains space separated values. On on the column I have only zeros. Example:

```
... # there is more configuration before the interesting stuff:
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.54:12131
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.55:12102
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.49:12333
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.60:12184
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.62:12888
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.77:12001
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.33:12973
```

Now I want to increment the second column with its index.
that is I want this result:

```
0 0 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.54:12131
0 1 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.55:12102
0 2 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.49:12333
0 3 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.60:12184
0 4 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.62:12888
0 5 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.77:12001
0 6 file /dev/stdin 224.0.68.33:12973
```

How to to that in emacs lisp? Or any other Emacsen way of doing thing please?

Comment: when reaching "10" the line shall get one character longer?

Comment: @PeterMiehle yes it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a macro with a counter to do that.  You start defining a macro with <kbd>F3</kbd> and end the definition with <kbd>F4</kbd>.  While defining the macro, hitting <kbd>F3</kbd> again will insert the value of the counter and increment it.  After defining the macro, run it by hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>.

So in your case, move point to the beginning of the first interesting line, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> <kbd>C-d</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>C-n</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> (i.e. remove the second zero, insert the counter, and move to the beginning of the next line).  Then hit <kbd>F4</kbd> as many times as needed to change all the lines.

If you need to change the value of the counter, use `M-x kmacro-set-counter`.

Comment: Ok that's a nice answer. I didn't knew the <kbd>F3</kbd> tricks to have an incremented counter while defining a macro. Thnx for that. By the way, I would have used <kbd>M-D</kbd> instead of  <kbd>C-D</kbd>. Because I can have numerics longer that one character. My example was not clear about, as a consequence your answer is perfectly valid :)

Comment: For the record: <kbd>F3</kbd> was not working for me. But <kbd>C-x C-k C-i</kbd> (`kmacro-insert-counter') was! :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the possibility to search and replace by an evaluated expression:

- put the point on the first line to process
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> query-replace-regexp <kbd>RET</kbd>
- searched string: `^0 \([0-9]+\)`
- replace with: `\,(format "0 %s" (+ \#1 \#))`

The meaning is:

- search a number preceded by a single zero at the beginning of the line
- replace by the result of the evaluation where `\#1` is the first matched group (like \1 but converted to number) and `\#` is the number of replacements already done (begins at 0 for the first replacement). The expression is evaluated for each match.

If the first number is not always a zero, I would use:

- searched string: `^\([0-9]+\) \([0-9]+\)`
- replace with: `\,(format "%s %s" \#1 (+ \#2 \#))`

Answer (score 7):

Similarly to Jonathan Leech-Pepin's answer, you can also use the non-cua rectangle editing commands (albeit in two steps instead of one).

- Set mark and point to the corners of the column rectangle
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to delete the rectangle.
- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to insert a number sequence in its place.

Also see related question:
[emacs string-insert-rectangle vector of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922539/emacs-string-insert-rectangle-vector-of-numbers/9932745)

Answer (score 4):

Something you could do using `org-mode` (I'm not sure of how will you use the result, but this can be one way of doing it)

```
| N | X | file | stream     |                ip |
|---+---+------+------------+-------------------|
| 0 | 0 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.54:12131 |
| 0 | 1 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.55:12102 |
| 0 | 2 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.49:12333 |
| 0 | 3 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.60:12184 |
| 0 | 4 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.62:12888 |
| 0 | 5 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.77:12001 |
| 0 | 6 | file | /dev/stdin | 224.0.68.33:12973 |
#+TBLFM: $2=@#-2
```

Some explanation, or rather, how to get your original data and transform it into this table:

- Copy your data into file config.org
- Create the table by basic string replacement commands. (Just copy the text as you have it now, select all of it and then <kbd>C-c |</kbd>)
- The `#+TBLFM:` part is the "formula" for this table, it means the following: assign to every cell in the second column the ordinal of it's row minus 2 (they start counting rows at 1, and this table has a header row).
- Whenever you <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on the formula, it will re-apply it to the table (so you can append more rows as you modify the document, reapplying the formula will automatically update the table.)

Comment: This is a more convenient method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cua-set-rectangle-mark`.

Evaluate:

```
(cua-mode 't)
```

Then in the buffer you can use `M-x cua-set-rectangle-mark` at the second column then extend the rectangle down to the end of the list.

Then use `M-n` (sequence), the defaults of `Start (0):`, `Increment (1):` and `Format (%d):` all provide what you need in this case.

Comment: I generally recommend having `cua-selection-mode` on permanently -- you get the nice rectangle features available by default, without all the cut/copy/paste stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here a very easy way to do this (using the same technique as [Seki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921961/65889) but easier):

Select all the lines you want the increment to appear in, then issue

```
M-x replace-regexp "^0 0" "0 \#"
```

or in more detail:

- `M-x replace-regexp RET`
- Searched string: `^0 0`
- Replace with: `0 \#`

This will give you the desired result, because `\#` replaces to the number of replacements done.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem all the time, and I don't enjoy setting up complicated rectangles or macros. So I created an elisp function to do it for me in a single command. I call it...*drumroll*...the `downcrementer`

Placing your cursor on the second 0 in your example and running `M-x downcrementer` will sequentially increment all the numbers in the column in one shot.

```
(defun downcrementer--bounds-of-num-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let (num-start num-end)
    (save-excursion
      (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
      (setq num-start (point)))
    (save-excursion
      (skip-chars-forward "0-9")
      (setq num-end (point)))
    (list num-start num-end)))

(defun downcrementer (&optional prefix-arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((current-number (string-to-number
                         (apply #'buffer-substring-no-properties
                                (downcrementer--bounds-of-num-at-point))))
        (stride 1)
        (orig-truncate-lines truncate-lines))
    (when prefix-arg
      (setq stride (string-to-number (read-string "Enter stride: "))))
    ;; Prevent wrapping from causing next-line to go to the wrong place
    (toggle-truncate-lines t)
    (next-line)
    (let ((first-column (current-column)))
      (while (thing-at-point 'number t)
        (save-excursion
          (apply #'delete-region (downcrementer--bounds-of-num-at-point))
          (setq current-number (+ current-number stride))
          (insert (number-to-string current-number)))
        (next-line)
        (move-to-column first-column))
      (previous-line)
      (move-to-column first-column))
    ;; Restore original truncate-line setting
    (toggle-truncate-lines orig-truncate-lines)))
```