# Rearrange file names in Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, file-rename, dired

I have a batch of files with the same format say `bmp`, the file name is `0.bmp` `1.bmp` ... `99.bmp`, I want to change the file names, say `0.bmp` to `99.bmp`, `1.bmp` to `98.bmp` etc. can emacs do this in `dired-mode`? I use emacs under Windows.

Comment: after searching for some questions, I find http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510716/930125 solve a similar problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use <kbd>M-x wdired-change-to-wdired-mode</kbd> to make a dired buffer editable. Afterwards a simple keyboard macro with [a counter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html), starting from the end of the dired buffer, should do the trick for you.

If you don't want to use a macro an alternative would be:

```
M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: ^[0-9]+
Replace regexp with \,(- 99 \#&)
```

Comment: Mmm... this will transform `0.bmp` into `1.bmp`. The OP wants to transform 0 into 99, 1 into 98, etc. Can be done similarly changing the regexp calculation, though to `(- 99 \#&)`.

Comment: Ops, I totally misread that. Updated my answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I want, since I know little about `emacs-lisp`.

Answer (score 2):

May be a quick a dirty answer, not generic:

First: <kbd>C-x C-q</kbd> in `dired-mode`;

Second: <kbd>M-:</kbd> yank and <kbd>RET</kbd> the snippet:

```
(progn 
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while (re-search-forward "\\([0-9]+\\).bmp" nil t)
    (replace-match
     (format "%d.bmp" (- 99 (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
     nil
     nil)))
```

Third: <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to save changes, and done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of `dired-mode`, but you can execute a simple script in the `*scratch*` buffer. As you're replacing existing file names with different names, I recommend you to do a first rename to all the files ant then start right with those names:

```
 (progn 
  (dotimes (i 100) 
    (let ((file-name (concat (number-to-string i) ".bmp")))
      (rename-file file-name (concat "old" file-name))))
  (dotimes (i 100)
    (let ((file-name-old (concat "old" (number-to-string i) ".bmp"))
          (file-name-new (concat (number-to-string (- 99 i)) ".bmp")))
      (rename-file file-name-old file-name-new))))
```

If you copy that to the `*scratch*` buffer and, *past* the expression you push <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>, that code will do it for you.